# can i initialize when inherited with ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I want to self-initialize a class when it is inherited, but it seems `inherited` gets called before the inherited class is loaded. is this perhaps bad form?

```
class Foo
  def self.inherited klass
    klass.new
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def initialize
    puts 'initialize'
  end
end
```

Comment: No. `inherited` is called after the inherited class is loaded, and after `Bar` is created, but before `initialize` is defined.

Comment: good to know. if you post as an answer, i can mark it as the correct one